# when will the service be killed in Lollipop?

Tags: android, service

I've created music streaming application and I have a service that when I play music I start this service as a foreground service which is linked to the notification and it works well in android 6,7,8 but i have a problem in android 5.
i want to know that when I startForeground and then stopForeground the service in android 5. when will the service be killed?

Comment: Please explain in detail, such as put your code with it

Comment: there is a PlayerService that extends Service in my application and i am handling the logic of my music player in it. and when the service is destroyed I do some actions e.g clear song data. and it works fine in android 6 ,7 ,8 but in android 5 i dont know what will happen to a service which is in background after  a long time @ShubhamVala